# How to correctly use trait objects , mutably iterating over mutable trait objects container, while mutating container itself?

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a packet parser, where basically one builds up a packet by parsing each Layer in the packet. The packet then holds those 'layers' in a vector.

The ~pseudo code~ code with compilation errors  is something like the following -

Also added comments below - for each step. I have experimented with  `RefCell` , but could not get that working. Essentially the challenges are enumerated at the end of the code.

The basic pattern is as follows - Get the object of a Layer type (Every Layer type will return a `default` next object based upon some field in the current layer as a 'boxed trait object'.)

**Edit:** I am adding a code that's more than a pseudo code - Also added following compilation errors. May be a way to figure out how to fix these errors could solve the problems.!

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Packet<'a> {
    data: Option<&'a [u8]>,
    meta: PacketMetadata,
    layers: Vec<Box<dyn Layer<'a>>>,
}

pub trait Layer<'a>: Debug {
    fn from_u8<'b>(&mut self, bytes: &'b [u8]) -> Result<(Option<Box<dyn Layer>>, usize), Error>;
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct PacketMetadata {
    timestamp: Timestamp,
    inface: i8,
    len: u16,
    caplen: u16,
}

impl<'a> Packet<'a> {
    fn from_u8(bytes: &'a [u8], _encap: EncapType) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let mut p = Packet::default();

        let eth = ethernet::Ethernet::default();

        let mut layer: RefCell<Box<dyn Layer>> = RefCell::new(Box::new(eth));
        let mut res: (Option<Box<dyn Layer>>, usize);
        let mut start = 0;
        loop {
            let mut decode_layer = layer.borrow_mut();

            // process it
            res = decode_layer.from_u8(&bytes[start..])?;

            if res.0.is_none() {
                break;
            }

            // if the layer exists, get it in a layer.
            let boxed = layer.replace(res.0.unwrap());
            start = res.1;

            // append the layer to layers.
            p.layers.push(boxed);
        }
        Ok(p)
    }
}
```

Compilation Errors

```rust
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `decode_layer`
  --> src/lib.rs:81:9
   |
68 |             res = decode_layer.from_u8(&bytes[start..])?;
   |                   ------------ `decode_layer` is borrowed here
...
81 |         Ok(p)
   |         ^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `layer`
  --> src/lib.rs:81:9
   |
65 |             let mut decode_layer = layer.borrow_mut();
   |                                    ----- `layer` is borrowed here
...
81 |         Ok(p)
   |         ^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors; 3 warnings emitted
```

It's not clear why the above errors come. I am using the values returned by the calls. (The 3: warnings shown above can be ignored, they are unused warnings.)

The challenges -

1. `p.layers.last_mut` and `p.layers.push` are simultaneous mutable borrows - not allowed. I could somehow put it behind a RefCell, but how that's not clear.
2. This code is similar in pattern to `syn::token::Token`s, however one basic difference being, there an `Enum` is used(`TokenTree`). In the above example I cannot use `Enum` because the list of protocols to be supported is potentially unbounded.
3. I cannot use `Layer` trait without `Trait Objects` due to the `loop`  construct.
4. The pattern can be thought of as - mutably iterating over a container of Trait objects while updating the container itself.
5. Perhaps I am missing something very basic.

Comment: Why do you put a lifetime on your `Layer` trait that you never use?

Comment: Your comment "I cannot use Enum because the list of protocols to be supported is potentially unbounded". Why not? You can set the `enum` to `non_exhaustive` allowing you to add more "protocols" in the future

Comment: @WBuck I don't think that's what OP means. I believe the intention is that any end user can decide to implement the `Layer` trait and `Packet` should work with it, which an enum cannot handle.

Comment: As a last resort, I would add an `Enum`. But would want to avoid that ideally. Regarding the lifetime for the layer, it's a remnant from some experiment, but don't think that's really the issue as far as these errors that I am getting. But would clean it eventually.

Comment: In fact that lifetime on `Layer` was a problem!!!! :-( Argh!!!..  But it will help to understand why? :-) @Aplet123 can you please change your comment to answer? I will accept that as an answer!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above code is due to lifetime annotation on the `Layer` trait. If that lifetime annotation is removed, the above code indeed compiles with a few modifications as posted below -

```rust
// Layer Trait definition
pub trait Layer: Debug {
    fn from_u8(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) -> Result<(Option<Box<dyn Layer>>, usize), Error>;
}


impl<'a> Packet<'a> {
    fn from_u8(bytes: &'a [u8], _encap: EncapType) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let mut p = Packet::default();

        let eth = ethernet::Ethernet::default();

        let layer: RefCell<Box<dyn Layer>> = RefCell::new(Box::new(eth));
        let mut res: (Option<Box<dyn Layer>>, usize);
        let mut start = 0;
        loop {
            {
                // Do a `borrow_mut` in it's own scope, that gets dropped at the end.
                let mut decode_layer = layer.borrow_mut();
                res = decode_layer.from_u8(&bytes[start..])?;
            }

            if res.0.is_none() {
                // This is just required to push something to the RefCell, that will get dropped anyways.
                let fake_boxed = Box::new(FakeLayer {});
                let boxed = layer.replace(fake_boxed);

                p.layers.push(boxed);
                break;
            }

            // if the layer exists, get it in a layer.
            let boxed = layer.replace(res.0.unwrap());
            start = res.1;

            // append the layer to layers.
            p.layers.push(boxed);
        }
        Ok(p)
    }
}
```